# Is it possible to create an Eulerian trail (one that is not an Eulerian circuit) from a complete graph with 5 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

It is easy to create an Eulerian circuit in this case, but I am not able to create an Eulerian trail that is not also an Eulerian circuit. I am now wondering that might not be possible.

Comment: Hint: Look at the parity of the number of remaining edges out of each vertex.  Think about any complete graph on an odd number of vertices.

Comment: In fact, this is not possible for any complete graph on an odd number of nodes. Hint: Remove the first edge of the path.

Comment: @MichaelBurr they all have even degrees. Does that imply that finding a trail that is not a cycle is really impossible, given I will not have an odd degree vertex to start/end?

Comment: That’s part-way there.  Take a partial Eulerian trail.  Which vertices have an odd number of edges remaining that you could choose?